# Backpack advice?

Tags: mountain-bike, helmets, bags

I have a Camelbak Kudu 12 (http://shop.camelbak.com/kudu-12/d/1344) backpack. I've tried riding with it a few times but it's just not working.
Whenever I ride down a trail, the backpack hits the back of my helmet. Because my helmet has a click to tighten on the back, whenever my backpack hits the helmet it undoes it, making it bob around in front of my eyes. I cannot ride when I'm using this backpack, I've tried tightening the straps fully and everything.
Any tips? 
Cheers

Edit: this is the tension control on the helmet, as you can see you push it and it loosens. [image]

Update: I've cable tied the tension control together, so that when the backpack hits it, nothing happens. works great!

Comment: How high (or low) are you wearing it? Do you have the straps done tight? Are you a particularly short person?

Comment: @andy256 im wearing it just how it is. the back of it goes from the bottom of my back to my neck. I'm about 180cm

Comment: Maybe try loosening the shoulder straps, pulling it as far down as it goes and tightening the belt, then get on the bike, tug it down and check the belt is tight before taking up the slack in the shoulder straps and tightening the chest strap.  The idea is to get it low and staying low.  You might also try wrapping something over the helmet tension control.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UPss2FjMVPU

Comment: How about not using a backpack on a bike. Bike has frame to hold your things, you do not need your back.

Comment: @Willeke It is a hydration pack.  How do you do a hydration pack on frame?

Comment: @Blam thanks, maybe he's meaning water bottles? but I ride with a pump where my water bottle would sit, that's why I need the backpack.

Comment: @ChrisH I tried that, didn't work. I might put a cable tie through the helmet tension.

Comment: @Blam, by using one with a tube that comes up from the frame, I used one on my recumbent bike, but I know they are available for sit up bikes as well.

Comment: @Willeke I sure don't want a tube that attaches to me and the bike on a trail for when I fall and I don't want to spend the effort to suck liquid up a distance.

Comment: I have a POC and you kind of have a perfect storm.  It is low for skull coverage and that that head band come loose easily.

Comment: @Blam yeah I know. I've put a cable tie around it (mine I just tighten fully) and it's looking to be working properly. Just wish there was a 'proper' fix.